# GWT - CSS Animation not working

Tags: css, gwt

I have followed the tutorial in [CSS3 Animations][1]

[1]: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp and can not get it to work. I have a war\GWTCustomAnimation.css in which I have copy/past the code to the end of the file:

```
 div {
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: myfirst 5s;
 }

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    from {background: red;}
    to {background: yellow;}
 }

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myfirst {
    from {background: red;}
    to {background: yellow;}
 }
```

And then, as a test, changed my GWT java code so the style picks up "myfirst" for a Button:

```
//Create the colour choice buttons and add them to the HorizontalPanel "headingContainer".
//Pencil
final Button pencilButton = new Button("P");
//pencilButton.addStyleName("pencilButton");
pencilButton.addStyleName("myfirst");
headingContainer.add(pencilButton);
//Set the pencil colour to pencil.
pencilButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {   

        pencilColour = "black";  
    }
});
```

When I start or stop the application the whole page goes from red to yellow to clear. However, the "pencilButton" has no background. I am expecting the "pencilButton" to go from red to yellow to red. I am testing using Chrome version 38.0.2125.104 m.

I have tried adding "!important" as I needed this for the background colour to work on the button for style "pencilButton":

```
.pencilButton {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: black !important;
}
```

This had no effect on this occasion.

Once I have this simple test working I plan to try some CSS 3D animation.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, Glyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been experimenting and found that changing:

```
div {
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: myfirst 5s;
 }
```

to

```
.myfirst {
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: myfirst 5s;
 }
```

Works. Please be patient; I am a newbie at this.

Regards,

Glyn